# Two or more columns with flex gap in tailwind

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I created a custom class with `.columns` with those properties:

```
.columns {
    @apply flex flex-wrap gap-4 sm:gap-8 lg:gap-10
}
```

When I do `basis-1/2` and put some items init I have only one column.
I understand it is because of the gap that extends the width but how can I do it work with a gap on row and column?

Here is the whole code (There will be more items but didn't want to make this post that long):

```
<div class="columns">

                            

<div class="basis-1/2">
    <div class="bg-white rounded-lg p-10">
        <div class="flex flex-col text-left">
            <div class="mb-6">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/536/35" alt="Test" class="rounded w-12 h-12">
            </div>
            <h4 class="typo-h4 mb-4">
                 Title
           </h4>
            <p class="typo-p1 mb-8">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer finibus sodales commodo. Curabitur arcu arcu, pretium quis eros eu, lobortis convallis nulla. Curabitur gravida est odio, eget ornare tortor eleifend in. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam non molestie elit.           </p>
            <a href="#" class="typo-l1 pb-4">
                Read more →
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>   

</div>
```

Comment: what you want to do, illustrate with a screenshot!

Answer (score 1):

As far as for the row/column, if you want both the card in the same row including the `gap` classes you had given, just replace `flex-wrap` with `flex-row`.

Code given below

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="flex flex-row gap-4 sm:gap-8 lg:gap-10">

                           

<div class="basis-1/2">
    <div class="bg-yellow-50 rounded-lg p-10">
        <div class="flex flex-col text-left">
            <div class="mb-6">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/536/35" alt="Test" class="rounded w-12 h-12">
            </div>
            <h4 class="typo-h4 mb-4">
                 Title
           </h4>
            <p class="typo-p1 mb-8">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer finibus sodales commodo. Curabitur arcu arcu, pretium quis eros eu, lobortis convallis nulla. Curabitur gravida est odio, eget ornare tortor eleifend in. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam non molestie elit.           </p>
            <a href="#" class="typo-l1 pb-4">
                Read more →
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="basis-1/2">
    <div class="bg-yellow-50 rounded-lg p-10">
        <div class="flex flex-col text-left">
            <div class="mb-6">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/536/35" alt="Test" class="rounded w-12 h-12">
            </div>
            <h4 class="typo-h4 mb-4">
                 Title
           </h4>
            <p class="typo-p1 mb-8">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer finibus sodales commodo. Curabitur arcu arcu, pretium quis eros eu, lobortis convallis nulla. Curabitur gravida est odio, eget ornare tortor eleifend in. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam non molestie elit.           </p>
            <a href="#" class="typo-l1 pb-4">
                Read more →
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>  


</div>
```

> Please see code in full view

You can also achieve the same thing in the same column just by changing the flex direction from row to col.

Comment: Here I tried with 1/4 and 3/4 , but it is showing same 50% for both the columns. Helpful if you can guide here.